Drop out data due to death or hospitalization in WGEE
I have an RCT dataset of people aged 60 years or older who have been hospitalised for a cardiovascular event and discharged from hospital just prior to entering the study. Participants are randomly assigned to a control group or treatment group for a period of 12 months. I want to estimate the effect of the intervention on some secondary outcomes - continuous - of quality of life and perceived loneliness, as well as some biomarkers - HbA1c, CRP, etc. -.
The problem is that there are missing observations due to re-hospitalisation or death. I want to deal with this problem through Weighted GEE, but I have seen very little literature on structural drop outs specifically due to re-hospitalisation or death, nor do I know of any functions in R that deal directly with this problem. Any suggestions for packages in R that would adequately handle this issue?

Look for right-censoring due to death for more literature

This might be handled by a "joint model" of covariates and events, using a (conditional) mixed model for the covariates and survival analysis based on covariate values together. See this question for example, and this web page linked from it. This page has links to some implementations and some cautions about their interpretation. I don't know if there's an equivalent marginal model for the covariates.
